# Proof by induction verification: $A\subseteq B$ implies $A^+ \subseteq B^{+}$

Tags: solution-verification, computer-science, formal-languages

I tried the following induction proof:

- $\sum \neq \emptyset$
- $A,B \subseteq \sum^{*}$
- $A^{+} := \bigcup_{n\geq 1} A^n $
- $A^{n} :=$ "$n$-wise-concatenation of $A$ to itself"
- $AA := \{ab | a \in A \wedge b \in A\}$

To proof: "$A\subseteq B$ implies $A^+ \subseteq B^{+}$

a. Induction basis:

- $n=1$: $A^{1}\subseteq B^{1}=A \subseteq B. $

b. Induction step:

- Induction assumption: for a fixed $n$, $A\subseteq B$ implies $A^n \subseteq B^n$.
- Induction hypothesis: for a fixed $n$, $A\subseteq B$ implies $ A^{n+1} \subseteq B^{n+1}$.
- Proof of hypothesis:
  $ A^{n+1} = AA^{n}\subseteq BA^{n}= B \subseteq B  B^{n}=B^{n+1}$.

Last subset-relation holds because of the induction assumption, and the one before, because of the assumption $A \subseteq B$.

Is this a correct proof for this implication? What can I improve?

Comment: What is $A^+$ ?

Comment: n-wise-concatenation of the language with it self, A ∪ A^2 ∪ A^3 ∪ ... ∪ A^{n}$, for example: lets say language  A={a},A^2={aa}, and so on, A^+={a,aa,aaa,aaaa...}

Comment: @HaferFlockenPengu, I have changed the edit you made because it was not correct. You cannot assume that $A^+\subseteq B^+$, because that is not induction (not an assumption for certain $n$).

Comment: Is it "not an assumption for certain n" since A^{+} \subseteq B^{+} might not hold for certain set A,B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof says that, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, you have $A^n\subseteq B^n$, not more. You can't say that $A^+\subseteq B^+$, because there is no $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $A^m=A^+$ and $B^m=B^+$.

To finish the proof, consider some $a\in A^+$, then, there must be some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a\in A^k$. Therefore, by your proof by induction, you have that $a\in B^k\supseteq A^k$, therefore, $a\in B^+$. And this proves that $A^+\subseteq B^+$.

Comment: Why must "$a \in B^+$" hold?

Comment: Because we have proven that $a\in B^k$ and, by definition, $B^k\subseteq B^+$. This is, $a\in B^k\subseteq B^+$, therefore, $a\in B^+$.

Comment: Makes sense. Got it now, thank you very much.